# How to combine different css class selectors into one javascript line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can this code be simplified into one line (js statement)?

```js
     <script>$(".div2").click(function() {window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;});</script>
     <script>$(".div3").click(function() {window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;});</script>
     <script>$(".div4").click(function() {window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;});</script>
     <script>$(".div5").click(function() {window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;});</script>
     <script>$(".div6").click(function() {window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;});</script>
     <script>$(".div7").click(function() {window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;});</script>
     <script>$(".div8").click(function() {window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;});</script>
     <script>$(".div9").click(function() {window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;});</script>
```

Comment: Why not just put the same common class on all the elements?

Answer (score 2):

You can short it down to something like this:

```
$(".div2,.div3,.div4,.div5,.div6,.div7,.div8,.div9").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  return false;
});
```

Also there is no need to use multiple `<script>` tags, 1 is enought.

Answer (score 1):

Two answers:

### Selector group

You can use a [*selector group*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#grouping):

```
$(".div2, .div3, .div4, .div5, .div6, .div7, .div8, .div9")..click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

A selector group is a series of selectors with commas in-between. It selects elements matching any of the selectors in the group.

### Event delegation

Rather than adding a handler to all of those divs, you could add one to `document` that only takes action if the click passed through one of those divs:

```
$(document).on("click", ".div2, .div3, .div4, .div5, .div6, .div7, .div8, .div9", function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

---

Even if you had multiple statements, there's no reason you couldn't put them in a single `script`:

```
<script>
doThis();
doThat();
doTheOther();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a common class to elements, as follows.

```
<div class="div2 my-class"> ... </div>
<div class="div3 my-class"> ... </div>
<div class="div3 my-class"> ... </div>
<div class="div4 my-class"> ... </div>
<div class="div5 my-class"> ... </div>
<div class="div6 my-class"> ... </div>
<div class="div7 my-class"> ... </div>
<div class="div8 my-class"> ... </div>
```

add the event listener to that common class

```
$(".my-class").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  return false;
});
```